# how to apply Fast Fourier Transform using multiple .csv files

Tags: python, csv, fft

I am a beginner in python and i need help. I have a vibration data of 5 different pumps in .csv format each csv file  have 4 columns(time, ax, ay, and az) and multiple rows. Can anyone help me how to apply fast Fourier transform  and plot them and also how to plot them before applying fast fourier transform.
i try to plot them but could get the required and clear results. Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

# Import csv file
data = pd.read_csv("dry pump_6h data_acceleration.csv")
print(data.head()) 
# plot data
df.plot(linestyle = '', marker = '*', color='r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us any code you have written to solve it, which is not working?